# Positioning of div changes only in Firefox

Tags: html, css

What I want is: - to position a small 25px - 25px image at the end of a line of text. I'm using a DIV (re1DOC) to position the element to make it a bit easier. 
The problem is: once I have it positioned correctly it displays just as i want in IE & Chrome, but when I switch to FireFox, the text has shifted a little and the div is no longer where i wanted it. 
- I have validated my htlm & CSS with no issues. 
( i know the width, height & background colour attributes are not needed in my CSS, but it helped me set it all up and will be removed befor publishing.)

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Restless Earth</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
<link href="CSS/RE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="REbackground"> </div>
<div id="wordbox"> </div> 
<div id="textwrapper"> 
<p> The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart.  This shifting process is known as continental drift.</p> 
 <div id="world"> <img src="images/gcse images/platemovementIMG.gif" width="400" height="210" alt="plate movement"/></div>
 <p> The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart. </p> 

 This shifting process is known as continental drift. The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart.  This shifting process is known as continental drift. The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart.  This shifting process is known as continental drift. The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.<div id="re1DOC"><a href="documents/gcse/REspec.docx"><img src="images/DOC.png" width="25" height="25" alt="download"  /></a>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#REbackground {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 400px; 
    background-color: #F33;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #F00;
    background-image: url(../images/gcse%20images/eruption1.jpg);
}

#textwrapper {
    height: 4000px;
    width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #00F;
}

#world {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #F00;;
    width: 400px;
    height: 210px;
}

#re1DOC {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #0F0;
    width:25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: is this what you wanted?!! http://jsfiddle.net/8botsnL0/

Comment: Yes, spot on. that is what i was trying to achieve, where was I going wrong?     Also: i notice that FireFox is still moving the text around a bit, why does this occur?  Many Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by move text around exactly? and also if you found my answer acceptable please accept it as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the small 25x25 px image positioned right at the end of the paragraph, then you dont have to position it the way you did. If you check the fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/8botsnL0/ , all I did was give the < p > paragraph tag to the last paragraph ( which you had not done btw) and before you close the tag (/p) add your image with your anchor tag for linking. you do not need the extra div re1DOC. so your html looks like,

```css
#REbackground {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 400px; 
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #F00;
    /*background-image: url(../images/gcse%20images/eruption1.jpg);*/
}

#textwrapper {
    height: 4000px;
    width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #cecece;
}

#world {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #F00;;
    width: 400px;
    height: 210px;
}
/*  remove this not needed as per ur requirement
#re1DOC {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #0F0;
    width:25px;
    height: 25px;
}
*/
```

```html
<body>
<div id="REbackground"> </div>
<div id="wordbox"> </div> 
<div id="textwrapper"> 
<p> The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart.  This shifting process is known as continental drift.</p> 
 <div id="world"> <img src="images/gcse images/platemovementIMG.gif" width="400" height="210" alt="plate movement"/></div>
 <p> The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart. </p> 

<p> This shifting process is known as continental drift. The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart.  This shifting process is known as continental drift. The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.The position of Earth’s continents has changed over time with some landmasses colliding into one another and others moving apart.  This shifting process is known as continental drift. The evidence that supports continental drift includes: the jigsaw-fit of many of the land masses, the geological and fossil finds that are the same in different continents and the scientific measurments taken more recently that prove land masses are moving toward, away and alongside eachother. Continental drift is caused by convectional cell movement in the mantle.<a href="documents/gcse/REspec.docx"><img src="images/DOC.png" width="25" height="25" alt="download"  /></a></p>


</div>

</body>
```